# Django regroup and unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm trying to group my list by first letter with the following code:

```
{% regroup my_list|dictsort:"name"  by name.0 as my_list_1 %}
```

It works well with English / simple latin, but when it's comes to Cyrillic it just returns nothing. I think this happens because unicode name is multibyte, but how can I fight with that?

Comment: Can you show data with which this fails?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, well, for example with Cyrillic, when name is "Александр". I tried to do something like this name.decode()[:1] but it didn't help.